# How are paremeter types inferred when there are both generics and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-inference

I looked at the Comparator interface in java 8 offical documentation I saw this method

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> 
comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

In the parameter list we have **? extends U**, and in the diamond after static keyword, we have **? super U**.

- Question 1: How could U be inferred ?
- Question 2: The type of U is
  inferred at compile time or runtime?

In the java.util.stream package we have the stream classes, one of them is the following

```
public interface BaseStream<T,S extends BaseStream<T,S>>
```

- Question 3: Why can a type paremeter extends the class itself, how does it make sense?

Comment: Java generics are a compile-time-only feature. Generics are fully erased after compilation (into `Object` and plain old casts). So to answer `2.`: compile-time only. Java is able to make sure that your generic type system is 100% sane at compile-time. And then it removes the system as it is not needed anymore.

Comment: By the way, please try to avoid asking multiple questions in one SO question. You could just have posted this in 3 separate questions, then one would already be answered :) You would also have received triple the up-votes, as all questions would be valid and good questions.

Comment: For question 3, this makes sense if you think about for example `class Person implements Comparable<Person>` which means that a class can be compared to other instances of itself. It is quite helpful that Java supports this. Java even goes further and supports so called self-types. So `class Foo<T>` and then a usage of `Foo<Foo>`, which can be helpful in certain situations (mostly dealing with inheritance).

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks for the helpful tip and the great explanation!